# Finish animation on hover even mouse leave

Tags: css

I'm using CSS keyframes to rotate an element on its hover state.

How do I make the element finish its animation even the mouse leave the element before it actually end?

For example, if I move my mouse out of the element(stop hovering) while the element only rotating to 180 degree (the full animation is 360 degree), it immediately stop the animation and go back to its original state instead of finish the animation.

```css
#rotate {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: orange;
}

#rotate:hover {
  animation: rotating 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="rotate"></div>
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer for some clarity

Comment: If the intended animation is simply a rotation, this effect might be more easily achievable with a transition rule, rather than a keyframe animation.

Comment: @Loki, I attached a snippet with a working jQuery example

Comment: @Loki the transition will still cancel the animation on mouse leave...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Javascript for this, the following snippet is shown using some jQuery, a working example:

```js
$("#rotate").on({
   mouseenter() {
      $(this).addClass("animated"); 
   },
   animationend() {
      $(this).removeClass("animated");  
   },
});
```

```css
#rotate {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.animated {
  animation: rotating 1s ease 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes rotating {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="rotate"></div>
```

Make sure that the class `animated` is with the animation, and `#rotate` is the box you want to spin.

Comment: Nice work, but is it possible to make it just with vanilla JavaScript

Comment: It gets complicated with Vanilla. jQuery, on the other hand, is designed for clean solutions

Comment: Seems like you copied this code from an outdated resource. ***"As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated"*** `.bind()` is deprecated in favor of `.on()`. Here's a link [to the .bind() DOCS](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) Please next time when you use a foreign resource, try to provide a link to the original post or link to page, give kudos to the original answerers, posters.

Comment: Edited and improved your code...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for my situation as it pauses and starts from where it left off. For simple rotation, this feels nicer than the jump you usually get from hovering in and out.

```
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.name-star {
    right: 5px;
    top: 15px;
    animation: 5s rotate infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

.mat-grid-tile:hover .name-star {
    animation-play-state: running;
}
```